# Inheritance Code reusability

Tags: java, inheritance

**1:**

```
class arbitrary {
    void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello Inheritance");
    }
}
public class inheritance extends arbitrary {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        arbitrary ar = new arbitrary();
        ar.print();
    }
}
```

**Outputs:** Hello Inheritance

**2:**

```
class arbitrary {
    void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello Inheritance");
    }
}
public class inheritance extends arbitrary {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        inheritance in = new inheritance(); in .print();
    }
}
```

**Outputs:** Hello Inheritance

**3:**

```
class arbitrary {
    void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello Inheritance");
    }
}
public class inheritance {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        arbitrary ar = new arbitrary();
        ar.print();
    }
}
```

**Outputs:** Hello Inheritance

**4:**

```
class arbitrary {
    void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello Inheritance");
    }
}
public class inheritance {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        inheritance in = new inheritance(); in .print();
    }
}
```

**Outputs:** Error

**1st and 2nd** programs uses the concept of inheritance and re-usability, but in the **3rd program** the base class (i.e. inheritance) **not extends** the superclass (i.e. arbitrary) still it is running successfully .
So **without extending how it is possible to reuse the code from superclass?** can any one help me to figure out that how the 3rd program is able to run successfully without using the concept of inheritance and re-usability.

Comment: Eeew. At least indent your code.

Comment: can you please indent your code directly?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  The 4th program doesn't compile because you're trying to invoke a method called `print()` in an `inheritance` object, which doesn't define that method.  All the other examples define that method on the object being created.  The 3rd and 4th examples have nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: In the third code, you are simply using the code, not re-using it. In the fourth code, you are calling a method that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first and third programs are actually the same.

It doesn't really matter what the `Inheritance` class is extending, because you are not really using it. Your `main` is using only the `Arbitrary` class, and since the `Arbitrary` class has a `print` method, it succeeds and prints the message.

Your second example works because `Inheritance` extends `Arbitrary`, and you are using the `Inheritance` class for your object. Since it extends `Arbitrary`, it has all the methods of `Arbitrary`, and therefore has `print` and will print successfully.

But your forth example uses an `Inheritance` object. But despite its name, it does not extend `Arbitrary`, and has no methods other than `main`, meaning it also doesn't have a `print` method. Hence the error.

Your confusion perhaps stems from:

- Your belief that program 1 demonstrates inheritance. It doesn't, really. You are not using the extended class so there is no inheritance in use.
- Your belief that 3 and 4 have the same logic. They don't. Your 3rd is using the `Arbitrary` class that has a `print` method, but your 4th is using the `Inheritance` class, which doesn't have a `print` method.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd program works because you're creating an instance of the `arbitrary` class, and can therefore use it's methods by calling through the `arbitrary` object.

The 4th doesn't because there's zero connection to the `arbitrary` class. The method doesn't exist within the scope of the `inheritance` class.

Answer (score 0):

In the 4th code, `inheritance` class does not has any method called `print`, so it is giving error.

In the 3rd code, `arbitrary` object has a method called `print`, so it is running successfully.

In 2nd code, `inheritance` class in inherites `arbitrary` class, so it has a method called `print`.